# How to access a web service hosted on my AWS work space from internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Basically my problem is I want to do following things :

1. Develop a web service on work space
2. Now give demo of that web service usage from my AWS works space by a  public IP like
   http://172.23.0.1:8090
3. I want an IP for my workplace by which I can access web app or web service hosted locally on that machine to be accessed from any where from internet.

Is that possible if not then tell me alternative ?

Comment: Read about Elastic IP

Comment: i don't understand concept of region in elastic IP can you explain please ? is that IP only accessible in that region?

Comment: Elastic IP are useful for mapping your domain with the server. You can assign elastic IP to the any server associated to your account. But you do not need elastic IP here. Simple creation of Public IP will suffice your requirement. Reason for not using elastic IP is: You can only have `max` of 5 at a time + there is additional cost based on transfer of data via that IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps that you should follow:

- Select *Assign Public IP* while creating the new instance
- In the assigned *Security Group* settings, open the port `8090` for `0.0.0.0` (means accessible for all) along with the protocol you will be using (TCP, UDP, etc)